# Cross Validation confusion

Tags: regression, cross-validation, model-selection, residuals, intuition

I am a bit confused about what k-fold Cross Validatation does. Is it better to remove non significant variables and tune with k-fold cross validation or the other way around? Is it something more like a residual analysis, or it is a tool to tune the model, to get a the one with higher accuracy?